# Understanding the model training log statements

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, python-3.7

I am getting the following message when my model is getting trained. I would like to know what does  29/30 and 30/30 represent ?

```
    Epoch 1/80
    29/30 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1177 - acc: 0.5538Epoch 1/80
    30/30 [==============================] - 31s 1s/step - loss: 1.1189 - acc: 0.5540 - val_loss: 1.1182 - val_acc: 0.5741
    Epoch 2/80
    29/30 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.0194 - acc: 0.6063Epoch 1/80
    30/30 [==============================] - 24s 815ms/step - loss: 1.0149 - acc: 0.6075 - val_loss: 1.0946 - val_acc: 0.6136
```

Comment: 29/30 is the progress in batches, 29 batches finished from a total of 30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 29/30, 30/30 here all shows the progress of your training (fit call here).

30/30 also shows the last batch of one epoch and it will also validate the model against the val data if you specify the val_data, which is why you have val_loss and val_acc in 30/30 but no such info in 29/30.

```
Epoch 1/80
29/30 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.1177 - acc: 0.5538Epoch 1/80
30/30 [==============================] - 31s 1s/step - loss: 1.1189 - acc: 0.5540 - val_loss: 1.1182 - val_acc: 0.5741
```